# Define generic of impl is not an Option

Tags: generics, rust

Can I say this implementation is not for `Option<_>` or add priority for `impl`?

I know I can add type to `let y: Foo<_>`, but I want to use auto infer.

```rust
enum Foo<T> {
     Value(T),
     Some(T),
     None,
}

// only for non-option T types.
impl<T> From<T> for Foo<T>
// where !Option<_> ?
{ 
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        Foo::Value(value)
    }
}

impl<T> From<Option<T>> for Foo<T> {
    fn from(value: Option<T>) -> Self {
        match value {
            Some(value) => Foo::Some(value),
            None => Foo::None,
         }
    }
}

let the_string = "hello".to_string();
let the_string_option = Some("world".to_string());

let x: Foo<_> = the_string.into();
let y: Foo<_> = the_string_option.into();
```

```
let y: Foo<_> = the_string_option.into();
    -  ^^^^^^ cannot infer type
    |
    consider giving `y` the explicit type `with_name::tests::test_multi_value::Foo<_>`, with the type parameters specified
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code. But compiler do not know what implementation of `From`/`Into` to use, that is why it asks for the type hint.

It would be solved if you ever use the variable (`y` in this case) somewhere were is supposed to be of the expected type:

```rust
...
let y = the_string_option.into();
    
fn foo(v: Foo<String>) {}
foo(y)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e578bc73ae7e1685f38566c0b1c3cb4d)